# Search each element in string array for multiple terms using RavenDB and lucene

Tags: c#, lucene, ravendb

I have (among others) the follwing objects in my RavenDB:

`Object1`:

```
{
  "Texts" : [ "one two", "three four" ]
}
```

`Object2`:

```
{
  "Texts" : [ "one three", "two four" ]
}
```

I want to find all objects where a string in `Texts` contains both of the terms `one` and `two`.

If I index the field

```
from doc in docs.Objects select new { Texts }
```

and analyze it using the `StandardAnalyzer` the following query will return both `Object1` and  `Object2` when I only want `Object1`:

```
Texts:(one AND two)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it that way, you can do:

```
from doc in docs
from text in doc.Tests
select new { Text = text }
```

Note that this is a fan-out index, and if you have a lot of texts per document, that require paying attention to the resources required.

Comment: I see, and then I'd analyze the `Text` field? (I assume `Tests` is a typo and you meant `Texts`)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement aren't really compatible.
What about this document?

```
{
  "Texts" : [ "two one", "three four" ]
}
```

Do you want to find it when you search for `one AND two`?

If not, just do a phrase search, if yes, you can't really do what you want without using fanout.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to find that document as well. The important thing is to be able to perform the search. The query, indexes or whatever else is needed can be adapted.